# Detect HTML video change

Tags: javascript, html

If you have an html video, is there any way to set up an observer to watch for something like if the video changes color?

I’ve tried an async loop that watches the first pixel but it doesn’t actually let the video frames render while running

Comment: Interesting question! I went around looking and found this thing that might help you find the solution: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/